# How can I write a batch file that will delete all the files who exist in another directory?

Tags: batch-file

I want to write a batch file that will remove the file overlap between two folders.

In other words, I want it to say "Remove from folder A all files which also appear in folder B".

From a SQL point of view, it would be something like

```
DELETE FROM FOLDERA WHERE EXISTS(SELECT FILE FROM FOLDERB)
```

but I want to accomplish that in the windows filesystem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SET if_it_exists_here=C:\folderB
SET then_delete_it_there=C:\folderA
CD "%if_it_exists_here%"
FOR %%A IN (*.*) DO (
 IF EXIST "%then_delete_it_there%\%%~nxA" DEL /Q /F %then_delete_it_there%\%%~nxA
)
```

Comment: This is an interesting alternative.  Is there any special advantage to this approach?

Comment: This just looks for the file before deleting it as opposed to assuming the file exists and deleting it. So redirecting with `2>` should come out clean. I always test with redirecting `2> file > file2` to ensure nothing goes wrong with the code, and having it return "file not found" to STDERR is annoying =/. Just nitpicky.

Comment: Great points, I think I'll use this rather than my own.  I suspect it will perform better with large numbers of files, too.

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question:

```
set if_it_exists_here=C:\folderB
set then_delete_it_there=C:\folderA
cd "%if_it_exists_here%"
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir *.* /b /a:-d') DO del "%then_delete_it_there%\%%G"
```

Comment: i suppose its given that the file ALWAYS exists in both folderA and folderB?

Comment: No, not necessarily.  If there is no overlap, then the script will not delete anything.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the answer by Mechaflash, here is a version that works with UNC paths.

```
SET if_it_exists_here=\\server1\some\folder
SET then_delete_it_there=\\server2\some\folder
CD "%if_it_exists_here%"
FOR %%A IN ("%if_it_exists_here%\*.*") DO (
 IF EXIST "%then_delete_it_there%\%%~nxA" DEL /Q /F %then_delete_it_there%\%%~nxA
)
```