# delete older files who exist in another directory?

Tags: windows, batch-file, filesystems, xcopy, robocopy

I have two folders who have almost the same files and folders.

I want to consolidate them and delete all files in folderA that are the same in folderB (Same Date or Older)

Someone already asked [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7490840/how-can-i-write-a-batch-file-that-will-delete-all-the-files-who-exist-in-another) about just deleting files without checking for date.

I want something similar but it should only delete if its the same age or older.

Thank You

Comment: have you tried robocopy?

Comment: I just want to delete, not copy. Can that be done with robocopy?

Comment: yah, but i think i know a better way, give me a sec

Comment: I used robocopy to copy an old drive to a new drive but didn't use /MOV and now the drive is full. Need to clean up before I can continue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
@echo off&setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
pushd "%~dp0"


for /f %%i in ('dir /b a') do (call:CmpFTime LSS "a\%%~ni" "b\%%~ni"&&del "a\%%~ni")


:CmpFTime
SETLOCAL
set op=%~1
set fileL=%~2
set fileR=%~3
set attrL=%~4
set attrR=%~5
if "%op%"=="" set op===
if "%attrL%"=="" set attrL=/tw
if "%attrR%"=="" set attrR=%attrL%
for /f "tokens=1-6 delims=/: " %%a in ('"dir %attrL% /-c "%fileL%"|findstr "^^[0-1]""') do (
    set TL=%%c%%a%%b%%f%%d%%e
)
for /f "tokens=1-6 delims=/: " %%a in ('"dir %attrR% /-c "%fileR%"|findstr "^^[0-1]""') do (
    set TR=%%c%%a%%b%%f%%d%%e
)
if "%TL%" %op% "%TR%" (rem.) ELSE set=2>NUL
EXIT /b
```

if this contains any errors, feel free to comment, and i will do my best to fix them. i substituted a for foldera and b for folderb.

Comment: I didint try it because I needed a quick fix then and ended up doing something else. Thank You anyway, but i didint test the code.